# Iterate and create list of dicts

Tags: python

I need to iterate results to generate a list of dics with this structure:

```
items = [{'clients': [
         {'value': i[4], 'first_name': i[1], 'last_name': i[3]},
         {'value': i[4], 'first_name': i[1], 'last_name': i[3]} 
         ]
}]
```

---

```
for i in results:
       items = ?
```

EDIT

```
 [0] => tuple(5) 
        [0] => int(396043) 
        [1] => str(45) "First name"
        [2] => int(532) 
        [3] => str(45) "Second name"
        [4] => float(1.0) 
 [1] => tuple(5) 
        [0] => int(374286) 
        [1] => str(24) "First name"
        [2] => int(537) 
        [3] => str(24) "Second name"
        [4] => float(1.0)
```

How can i do that?

Comment: @user2983258: a tuple of *what* exactly? You need to edit your question and add more detail. There is not enough here to go on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just don't know how to create the structure that i want without be explicitly as i do.

Comment: @user2983258: Well, explaining that you want each `{'value': ...}` dictionary to be created from each tuple in `results` would be a start. Showing us sample input data and expected output data would be tremendous.

Comment: @user2983258: As it is I *think* I guessed what you wanted in my answer below, but none of us are able to know for certain unless you tell us more.

Comment: I'm not sure your edit makes it any clearer... and it looks like a PHP var_dump....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to generate the dictionaries based on each tuple in `results`:

```
items = [{
    'clients': [{'value': i[4], 'first_name': i[1], 'last_name': i[3]} for i in results]
}]
```

You could also use tuple assignment to produce more meaningful names in the loop

```
items = [{
    'clients': [{'value': value, 'first_name': first, 'last_name': last} 
                for _, first, _, last, value in results]
}]
```

You can do this in an explicit for loop too, but the list comprehension will be faster. The explicit loop version:

```
clients = []
items = [{'clients': clients}]
for _, first, _, last, value in results:
    clients.append({'value': value, 'first_name': first, 'last_name': last})
```

Here `_` is the name used by convention for a loop variable that we are ignoring. It simply signifies that we won't use `_` any further, but needed an assignment target.

Comment: Your answer is perfect, so the question is more or less clear, at least. Man, sometimes I can't understand SO. The question is so bad to get -4? Jesus christ..

Comment: @user2983258: it wasn't clear what part of the expected output you were trying to generate. I had to guess at it being the list of dictionaries in `items[0]['clients']`. For all we knew it could have been that the `items` list needed generating, for example.

Comment: @user2983258: In other words, I was *lucky* that I had guessed correctly. tMJ deleted his answer, but it answered a different interpretation of your question. I guess he felt my guess was more accurate, but his interpretation was just as valid, really.